# Ubuntu 18.04, Bluetooth is DEAD

Tags: bluetooth, 18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04  on my ASUS-X550L laptop. In the settings it says "No bluetooth  found. Plug in a dongle to use bluetooth."  I tried `sudo rfkill unblock all` and `systemctl restart bluetooth.service`. It didn't work.

Output of 
    `sudo rfskill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `systemctl status bluetooth.service`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

Output of `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x20 (or later)
[    0.062011] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.556640] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    2.453984] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)
[   24.429952] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[   37.043932] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[   37.055254] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
```

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: You could try https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms  I have no idea if it actually works

Comment: I've got the same issue after installing acpi package.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure for your case:

1. Verify the network driver.
2. Try the following commands:

   ```
   rfkill block bluetooth
   rfkill unblock bluetooth
   ```